# Exceeding C++'s largest integer datatype

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a combinations calculator and for the bigger calculations I end up hitting an overflow with `long long int` or `int64_t`. Is it possible to perhaps, at least, convert the number to something of this sort: 6.7090373691429E+19?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {


  std::string charset;
  int i, length; int64_t total = 0;

  std::cout << "Charset: ";
  std::cin >> charset;
  std::cout << "Length: ";
  std::cin >> length;

    for (i=0;i<(length+1);i++) {
        total += pow(charset.size(),i);
    }

    std::cout << "\nPossible combinations: " << total << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's no longer an int, that'd be a floating point number.

Comment: Use one of the many "bigint" libraries available for C++.

Comment: The largest integer in C++ can be found in `<cstdint>` as `std::intmax_t`. However, you probably want to use a bigint library.

Comment: You can print a `long long` in scientific notation if you want, but that doesn't change its size or range.

Comment: Yes, I guess bigint is the proper solution. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: @McJohnson you may want to check [Boost.MultiPrecission](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). It is remarkably simple to use, see e.g. one example [here](http://ideone.com/I42K4f).

Comment: ... or simply use Python

Comment: BTW, `pow` use floating point, so you mix  float` with `int`.

Comment: @LiorKogan ...or use Java's `BigInteger`.

Comment: There might be a better algorithm to solve this particular problem, what's the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to escape overflows as it's usual to end up with one in my case.

Comment: If it's sure that the numbers added are positive and that no number is smaller than the previous one (as in this example), then declaring `total` as float or double is totally fine. Of course the outcome will not be precise, but often you don't need it to be (as in this example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library does not include arbitrary size integer types.

You can use [Boost Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) for this. It has different backends, using dedicated libraries (e.g. GMP) and a custom backend without external dependencies (cpp_int).

Edit: To be fair, vsoftco already mentioned Boost Multiprecision in a comment.

Comment: I ended up using BigInt, but Boost Multiprecision is just as good.